“Through a door into a parallel universe” movie
I’m trying to find a little-known sci-fi movie I streamed quite a few years ago. It’s in color, in American English and had no actors who were well-known (at least not to me). From the quality of the picture, it was probably made the last 30 years or so.
When the main character goes through certain doors he keeps getting transported to an alternate universe/parallel reality which is very similar but still substantially different. He’s trying to get back to his original one.
There was a blonde, who was a love interest later in the movie (the actress who played her was a female wrestler in real life). The guy’s wife or original girlfriend somehow shows up, opens the door and throws the blonde through the door and, when they reopen the door, of course she’s gone.
It seems the guy may have had a daughter with him during the early part of the movie. I’m not sure of that, though; it’s been a long time since I’ve seen it.
Ring any bells?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

This sounds rather like Another Version of You, a fairly low-key film from 2018 directed by Motke Dapp.
The main character, played by Kristopher Wente, is called "Diggsy". He is given a magical key that allows him to travel between different alternate universes, trying to find the universe in which he can hook up with his one true love (Suzette). In the course of his travels he meets a blonde named Gwyneth, played by C.J. Perry Barnyashev who was indeed a WWE performer, "Lana".
I do not think Diggsy had a daughter with him in the first part of the film, but the relationship with his sister was indeed important, and she pops up at various times in the story.

That’s it! That’s it! You’re amazing, Clara Díaz Sanchez! Thank you, thank you, thank you!
